# How to get distinct dates from a datetime field

Tags: laravel

I have this field `valid_upto` which is a `datetime`, so if I do:

```
$dates = Game::where('week', $this->week)
  ->distinct('valid_upto')
  ->pluck('valid_upto');
```

It returns an array like:

```
  ["2022-09-08 19:20:00",
  "2022-09-11 12:00:00",
  "2022-09-11 15:25:00",
  "2022-09-11 19:20:00",
  "2022-09-12 19:15:00",]
```

But I only want the date part, like:

```
  ["2022-09-08",
  "2022-09-11",
  "2022-09-12",]
```

is there a way to do it directly in Laravel's ORM? I don't want to use a rawSelect or similar, I know I could apply `DATE('valid_upto') as d` in mySQL and Postgres, but I really like to use "general" approaches.

This would work:

```
foreach ($dates as $i => $d) $dates[$i]=explode(" ", $dates[$i])[0]
$dates = $dates->unique()
```

But I think its an horrible solution

Something I would like to do, instead of using that `foreach`, applying a lambda (like in Python) to the Collection and then use the distinct. But I don't know if Laravel has lambdas.

Comment: *"I don't want to use a rawSelect"* - I was in the process of writing an answer (essentially `Game::selectRaw("DISTINCT(to_char(valid_upto, 'yyyy-mm-dd')) AS valid_upto_date")`, or similar), until I saw that. Any reason why not? You've gone (or avoided) the 2 routes that I know of, which are `selectRaw()`, or a `foreach` / `->map()->unique()` after the fact, both of which have their pros and cons.

Comment: Maybe is because I think I don't fully understand Raws. Correct me if I'm wrong: I'd use a raw when I want to execute a function specific to the database. No examples comes to my mind, but say function x() works in MySQL but not in Postgres. That's what I want to avoid

Comment: Yes, you're correct. `selectRaw()`, `DB::raw()`, etc. are to execute things that Eloquent cannot, which is usually RDBMS-specific. If you wanted to handle both MySQL and Postgres, you'd have to write this as a function, check the driver, then use `DATE_FORMAT()` for MySQL, and `to_char()` for Postgres, etc. The other option is doing this in PHP, which works for small sets of data, but anything large and you might start to see performance hits.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel you can use [Mutators and Casters](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting) to determine how certain columns are formatted when you access them. Laravel applies the casting when the model is serialized to json or to an array. So your query could become:

```
$dates = Game::where('week', $this->week)
    ->distinct('valid_upto')
    ->get('valid_upto')
    ->toArray();
```

And if you apply a caster on your `Game` model like so:

```
protected $casts = [
    'valid_upto' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
];
```

that should get you a collection of the dates you want in the format you want.

Comment: That's interesting... is this cast "global" or can be case by case? Because in other parts of the app I'm interested also on the time.

Comment: the cast is global, so if you define a cast for a model's attribute, any time you retreive the attribute from the model, it will be cast to the type you set automatically. However, you can use temporary casts with `$user->mergeCasts()` like so: `$user->mergeCasts(['created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d']);`, which will only change the attribute on that instance of `$user`.

Comment: I've only used casting in a limited area, so you can find out more about casting dates and times by checking out the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting